# RxJs: is it good practice to unsubscribe from Observables when navigating away?

Tags: rxjs, unsubscribe

I am just getting into RxJs and Observables in general. I grasped the idea that often you can create "self-contained" Observable by utilizing "takeUntil()".

In one online-course I am watching the teacher says "I did not unsubscribe from anything in 10 years because I always use takeUntil() to create ending streams of events". This is his example:

```
var getElementDrags = elmt => elmt
    .mouseDowns.map(() => document.mouseMoves.takeUntil(document.mouseUps))
    .concatAll();
```

That is very nice for the "inner" Observables. But the one outer Observable on "mousedown" never really gets unsubscribed from...

Do we still need to unsubscribe from those?
Is it still good practice to unsubscribe/dispose when the user leaves the page?

Comment: In your code you're not subscribing to anything, so there's nothing to unsubscribe from.

Comment: @torazaburo: The code is a bit "pseudo" - but I think there was a subscription to get the "elmt.mouseDowns" Observable...

Answer (score 0):

In example you have - you are not subscribing to anything... RxJS is lazy, and it will subscribe to `mouseDowns` only when you will subscribe to resulting observable, and of course - it will unsubscribe from underlining observables when you will unsubscribe from resulting observable.

But, generally - yes, it is a good practice to unsubscribe when you are subscribing to something… But - while using RxJS, typically you will not need to subscribe manually, and when you need - chances are that you need subscription while app is running(so no need to unsubscribe).

The only exceptions are - when you are developing own operators, or connecting to something outside…

---

For example if you have react component and use life-cycle hocks for subscription to updates on mount, and unsubscribe when un-mounting.

Here is my library for that purpose https://github.com/zxbodya/rx-react-container - it combines observables, subjects and react component into new observable with renderable items...

```
const app$ = createContainer(
  App, // react component
  {totalCount$}, // observables with data
  {plusOne$, minusOne$} // observers for user actions
);

const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
const appSubscription = app$.forEach(renderApp=>render(renderApp(), appElement));
```

In result you have only one subscription to manage for a whole application(`appSubscription`), and no need to unsubscribe - since it is used while app is running.

The same thing, about routing and unsubscribe when navigating away - in simplified case you will have just `flatMapLatest` over observable with current location, that will return observable(like `app$` above) for each location…  And again you do not need to subscribe/unsubscribe manually - `flatMapLatest` will do it internally.